# Python .write only works in when writing to same directory as script

Tags: python

I'm trying to write to a file which is in a directory in the same location as the script, call it Directory_A.

When I do `this_file = open("Directory_A/output_file.txt", "w+")` then write to the file, it is always empty after. I am making sure to close the file as well.

Yet when I do `this_file = open("output_file.txt", "w+")` then write to the file, it works. Same exact code everywhere else, just this path is different. The directory exists, and it's even creating the file I want in the first example, but never writing to it.

For clarification, the directory is something like:

The python script: home/files/script.py

The Directory I'm trying to put the output file into: home/files/Directory_A/

The file I'm trying to create and write to (only creating at the moment): home/files/Directory_A/output_file.txt

Comment: Hi @Matt, the code looks fine, it should not create the problem. However, always try to use keyword `with` for file handling in python. Kindly paste more of the logic where you are actually writing something in these files.

Comment: Are you sure that the directory containing the script is also the current working directory?

Comment: @chepner Yes, this is the current working directory.

Comment: @nandal It's not the logic. I made sure of this by creating a new script and simply writing that open statement and a print("test") right under it. Only the second example worked. I am unable to write to a file in the directory Directory_A